# Canvas with jQuery- mouse moving into an area, and exiting

Tags: jquery, canvas, onmouseover, mouseenter, mouseleave

How would I code: 
When mouse enters predefined area in canvas, image appears (already sorted the image), when exiting said predefined area, it disappears again.

This is all using jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery will track hover/blur on the canvas element, but not on individual drawings inside the canvas. 
Images drawn on html canvas are not DOM elements. Instead they are like forgotten painted pixels on a canvas.
**These are the steps to apply a hover-effect to your canvas-image:** (1) Keep track of your image's definition (x,y,width,height) in a javascript object, (2) Listen for mousemove events on the canvas, (3) Test if the mouse is inside your image, (4) When the mouse enters or leaves your circle, redraw or clear your image. Give a try coding and come back if you have coding problems.

Comment: Yeah i've already tried this, the issue is when I move into the space, the predefined shape comes up, however only for a split second until I move onto the next pixel, therefore just creating a flashy image/no image if the mouse is not moving. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Yep, just create a lastStatus flag that indicates if the previous mousemove was inside or outside the image. That way you only have to show/clear when lastStatus changes. This eliminates the flashing caused by redrawing your image with every mousemove inside the image. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers for the quick response, problem is if you don't use the mouse the shape disappears instantly, so if you move the mouse to the area, and don't move it the shape will disappear. (Your help is a life saver by the way)

Comment: I added an answer with a code example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will track hover/blur on the canvas element, but not on individual drawings inside the canvas. Images drawn on html canvas are not DOM elements. Instead they are like forgotten painted pixels on a canvas.

These are the steps to apply a hover-effect to an image draw inside your canvas:

1. Keep track of your image's definition (x,y,width,height) in a javascript object,
2. Listen for mousemove events on the canvas,
3. Test if the mouse is inside your image,
4. When the mouse enters or leaves your circle, redraw or clear your image.

To make your hover/blur more efficient, keep track of the previous image status (visible/not visible) and don't do anything if it hasn't changed status.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

var lastMouseWasIn;
var currentMouseIsIn=false;
var imgDef={x:30,y:30};

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolSmall.png";
function start(){

  imgDef.width=img.width;
  imgDef.height=img.height;

  draw();

  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}

function draw(){
  if(lastMouseWasIn===currentMouseIsIn){return;}
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  if(currentMouseIsIn){
    ctx.drawImage(img,imgDef.x,imgDef.y);
  }
  ctx.strokeRect(imgDef.x,imgDef.y,imgDef.width,imgDef.height);    
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  currentMouseIsIn = x>imgDef.x 
  && x<imgDef.x+imgDef.width 
  && y>imgDef.y 
  && y<imgDef.y+imgDef.height;

  draw();

  lastMouseWasIn=currentMouseIsIn;

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse in and out of rectangle to show/hide image.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```